# Samba - WebDAV - SFTP

Tags: sftp, samba

I have an external online space and I can access the disk with SFTP, Samba or WebDAV. Which of these methods are the most secure? I am planning to copy about 200MB of data per day.

Comment: Define "most secure"?

Answer (score 1):

**SFTP** is secure as underlying SSH, which is usually good, if the implementation is reasonable and proper cipherset is chosen.  If you don't go down to version 1, you are usually good.

**WebDAV** can be using TLS (over HTTP), which had several flaws and you can use some broken versions. But also depends on configuration.

**Samba** can use encryption since version 3.3. But also it does not have to.

This is really broad, opinion based and you didn't specify the most of the important variables. I would choose `sftp` for world-wild-web.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have a weak password for your sftp user, it will (by default) expose the whole folder structure of your server, as readable by that user, to anyone who logs in. If your WebDAV server is misconfigured, anyone can modify the uploaded contents. And various versions of Samba provide all kinds of ways into servers for malicious people.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, you are right. You can set up weak password everywhere, but since there is selection between these three in one place, I believe there will be some shared password and if you set it week, you break all of the services. If you have got notes to WebDav/Samba where I am not so knowledgeable, feel free to update the answer.